# Error message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined" with "ionic cordova build android --prod"

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

When running the command "ionic cordova build android --prod" generates the error below, I searched for several solutions and tried some of them but the error still persists.

Below some information about my environment:
ionic information

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 6.10.1 (C:\Users\sadem\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.3

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : not available
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.0.5, (and 13 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   NodeJS : v12.18.2 (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.14.5
   OS     : Windows 10
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-chooser": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-opener": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.5",
    "@pluritech/ion-mask": "^1.2.0",
    "build": "0.1.4",
    "cordova": "^9.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-browser": "^5.0.4",
    "cordova-ios": "5.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "^3.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-filechooser": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-filepath": "^1.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": "^2.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-webview": "0.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "device": "0.3.9",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-native": "^2.9.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "tslib": "^1.11.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.3",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3"
  },
```

```
[11:41:52]  copy finished in 15.93 s 
[11:42:19]  ionic-app-script task: "build" 
[11:42:19]  Error: ./node_modules/@ionic/angular/fesm5/ionic-angular.js Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read 
            property 'kind' of undefined at isAngularDecoratorMetadataExpression 
            (D:\Projetos\Mobile\condowebionic-Final-0.41\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:245:35)
            at checkNodeForDecorators 
            (D:\Projetos\Mobile\condowebionic-Final-0.41\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:67:21)
            at visitNodes 
            (D:\Projetos\Mobile\condowebionic-Final-0.41\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:12699:30)  
            at Object.forEachChild 
            (D:\Projetos\Mobile\condowebionic-Final-0.41\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:12875:24)  
            at checkNodeForDecorators 
            (D:\Projetos\Mobile\condowebionic-Final-0.41\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:58:31)
            at visitNode 
            (D:\Projetos\Mobile\condowebionic-Final-0.41\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:12690:24)  
            at Object.forEachChild 
            (D:\Projetos\Mobile\condowebionic-Final-0.41\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:12782:21)  
            at checkNodeForDecorators 
            (D:\Projetos\Mobile\condowebionic-Final-0.41\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:58:31)
            at visitNode 
            (D:\Projetos\Mobile\condowebionic-Final-0.41\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:12690:24)  
            at Object.forEachChild 
            (D:\Projetos\Mobile\condowebionic-Final-0.41\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:12828:24)  
            @ ./src/pages/configuracao-morador-remover/configuracao-morador-remover.ts 9:0-51 @ 
            ./src/pages/configuracao-morador-remover/configuracao-morador-remover.module.ngfactory.js @ ./src lazy @ 
            ./node_modules/ionic-angular/util/ng-module-loader.js @ ./node_modules/ionic-angular/module.js @ 
            ./node_modules/ionic-angular/index.js @ ./src/app/app.module.ts @ ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js @ 
            ./src/app/main.ts 
Error: ./node_modules/@ionic/angular/fesm5/ionic-angular.js
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
    at isAngularDecoratorMetadataExpression (D:\Projetos\Mobile\condowebionic-Final-0.41\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:245:35)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (D:\Projetos\Mobile\condowebionic-Final-0.41\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:67:21)    at visitNodes (D:\Projetos\Mobile\condowebionic-Final-0.41\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:12699:30)
    at Object.forEachChild (D:\Projetos\Mobile\condowebionic-Final-0.41\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:12875:24)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (D:\Projetos\Mobile\condowebionic-Final-0.41\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:58:31)    at visitNode (D:\Projetos\Mobile\condowebionic-Final-0.41\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:12690:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (D:\Projetos\Mobile\condowebionic-Final-0.41\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:12782:21)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (D:\Projetos\Mobile\condowebionic-Final-0.41\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:58:31)    at visitNode (D:\Projetos\Mobile\condowebionic-Final-0.41\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:12690:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (D:\Projetos\Mobile\condowebionic-Final-0.41\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript @ ./src/pages/configuracao-morador-remover/configuracao-morador-remover.ts 9:0-51
 @ ./src/pages/configuracao-morador-remover/configuracao-morador-remover.module.ngfactory.js
 @ ./src lazy
 @ ./node_modules/ionic-angular/util/ng-module-loader.js
 @ ./node_modules/ionic-angular/module.js
 @ ./node_modules/ionic-angular/index.js
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
 @ ./src/app/main.ts
    at new BuildError (D:\Projetos\Mobile\condowebionic-Final-0.41\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\util\errors.js:16:28)
    at callback (D:\Projetos\Mobile\condowebionic-Final-0.41\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\webpack.js:121:28)
    at D:\Projetos\Mobile\condowebionic-Final-0.41\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:265:13
    at Compiler.emitRecords (D:\Projetos\Mobile\condowebionic-Final-0.41\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:371:38)
    at D:\Projetos\Mobile\condowebionic-Final-0.41\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:258:10
    at D:\Projetos\Mobile\condowebionic-Final-0.41\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:364:12
    at next (D:\Projetos\Mobile\condowebionic-Final-0.41\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:218:11)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (D:\Projetos\Mobile\condowebionic-Final-0.41\node_modules\webpack\lib\performance\SizeLimitsPlugin.js:99:4)
    at Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries1 (D:\Projetos\Mobile\condowebionic-Final-0.41\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:222:13)
    at Compiler.afterEmit (D:\Projetos\Mobile\condowebionic-Final-0.41\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:361:9)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ionic-app-scripts.

        ionic-app-scripts.cmd build --prod --target cordova --platform android exited with exit code 1.
```

The "ionic serve" and "ionic Cordova prepare android" work without errors

Any suggestion will be really appreciate.

Comment: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/20924  refer this link please

Comment: Hi Kevin, 
I saw this link but it refers to Ionic 5, I have Ionic 3.x yet

Is there something to ionic 3?